# jQuery access to frame inside iframe on fully loaded frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need get access to element inside in frame inside in inframe with jQuery.

I have this struct:

```
<iframe id="frame1">
  <frameset id="frameset">
    <frame id="frame2"> <div id="exampleDiv">text</div> </frame>
  </frameset>
</iframe>
```

and script:

```
$("#frame1 #frameset #frame2").load(function () {
    $('#exampleDiv').hide();
});
```

but this script is not working

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you liked frames, so I put a frame in your iframe, so you can frame while you're framin'

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921957/how-to-access-frame-not-iframe-contents-from-jquery or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941855/jquery-access-frame-in-nested-frameset :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the jquery content() to retrieve the content of an iframe then use the .find() method but the document in the frame should be in the same domain that the parent document.

in this case :

```
 $("#frame1").contents().find("#exampleDiv").hide()
```

Comment: `alert($("#frame1").contents().find("#exampleDiv").html());`is null; `alert($("#frame1").contents().find("#frame2").contents().find("#exampleDiv").html());` is null :(

Comment: `$($("#frame1").contents().find("#frame2")[0].contentDocument).find('#exampleDiv').html()` <- The internet is horrible.