# How to get an element in a parent frameset with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page with frames within a frameset:

```
<FRAMESET>
    <FRAMESET >
        <FRAME name="menu" src=<%=menu%>>
        <FRAME marginWidth="0" src=<%=bottom%> >
    </FRAMESET>
    <FRAMESET>
        <FRAME src=<%=title%>>
        <FRAME name="main"src=<%=main%>>
    </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
```

I'm in the `main` frame and i neet to get a `myspan` `span` who is in the `menu` frame.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941855/jquery-access-frame-in-nested-frameset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite I don't like the index to get the `menu` frame, this worked:

`var mySpan = $('#myspan', window.parent.frames[0].document);`